# Strict Standards: while selecting data s from database using php pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I want to select data from my database, it was working very fine in localhost but when i upload in it was showing this error `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/account/public_html/cosrc/config.php on line 28`
At line 28 i want to use client ip to select in where clause so i change the `bindParam` to `bindValue` and i got same error in line 23 the output from line 23 from database should be like this data1,data2,data3,etc...

```
    <?php
//Here i select from main content
    $CheckOrSeesion = new DBController();
    $CheckOrSeesion->prepare("SELECT * FROM jailorgname j INNER JOIN users u ON j.jailorgnowner = u.username WHERE orgname = :checkOName LIMIT 1");
    $CheckOrSeesion->bind(':checkOName', $currentBas);
    $CheckOrSeesion->execute();
    $OrgFound = $CheckOrSeesion->getOne(); 
    $CheckOrSeesion->free();

    if($OrgFound){
    $orgname = $OrgFound->orgname;
    $jailorgnowner = $OrgFound->jailorgnowner; 
    $OrgDescription = $OrgFound->OrgDescription;
    $OrgUphoto = $OrgFound->photo;
    $OrgUjlikes = $OrgFound->jlikes;
    $OrgUjviewers = $OrgFound->jviewers;
    $Orgratstar = $OrgFound->ratstar;
    $Orgjaildate = $OrgFound->jaildate;
    $Orgjtags = $OrgFound->jtags; // Line 23
    }
//Here i check if user ip have view the post
    $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
    $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $Checkviewed = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(uip) FROM jailviewmap WHERE uip = :uip AND jailname = :jailname  LIMIT 1");
    $Checkviewed->bindValue(':uip', getUserIP()); //Line 28
    $Checkviewed->bindParam(':jailname', $currentBas);
    $Checkviewed->execute();
    $yesvi = $Checkviewed->fetchColumn();

    if(empty($yesvi) OR $yesvi == 0){
//Here if not viewed i insert it in view map
    $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
    $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $addviewMap = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO jailviewmap(jailname,uip)VALUES (:jailname,:uip)");
    $addviewMap->bindParam(':jailname',$currentBas);
    $addviewMap->bindParam(':uip', getUserIP());
    $addedMap = $addviewMap->execute();
    }
    ?>
```

Please there is a better way to reduce executing database query i will also appreciate if i can use i single select with union to check what i want

Comment: Try putting user IP into a variable ($userIp = getUserIP();) and then pass the variable itself on line 28 as the error suggests.

Comment: @Janno what about line 23?

Comment: Write the exact error you're getting on line 23.

Comment: @Janno what about line 23? and i got new error on line 22 `$Orgratstar = $OrgFound->ratstar;` integer value numbers

Comment: Write the exact error you're getting on these lines.

Comment: @Janno the same error `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in `